# Basemap Installation Error -Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have been following the instructions on the documentation page of basemap to install the module.  http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

However, when I ran setup.py I received the following

error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/_geoslib.o -lgeos_c -lgeos -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_geoslib.cpython-34m.so" failed with exit status 1

Any advice on how to fix this installation.  I also noticed that basemap hasn't been had a new release in years.  Is this module no longer supported?

Comment: Why would you think basemap is no longer supported? The last commit [on its GitHub page] was 2 days ago!

Comment: The installation guide led to a tarball from three years ago.  I went to github and was able to download successfully.